# Geometry Nodes - Get Index of corner conected by an edge

Tags: geometry-nodes

### What I am trying to achieve with geometry nodes:

1. Generate curve for each corner of a mesh - Done.
2. Set start and end points of these curves by positions of Next and Previous edge of a coresponding corner - Done.
3. Set handle positions of start and end points of the curves - I am stuck on that part.

To compute one of the handle positions corresponding to corner A, I need the positions (and therefore indexes) of the edges A_prev, A_next, and B_prev. I can get indexes of A_prev and A_next with Edges Of Corner node. **How can I get index of B_prev edge from index of corner A?**
[image: Mesh diagram]
**My current setup:**
I tried to use the new Corners Of Edge node. My idea was to feed in index of corner A, get index of edge A_next, and get index of corner B by sorting the cornes by distance to the corner A.

This setup works fine, if I plug in some concrete number as an index, but fails, when the Index node is used as source of indexes.

I also tried some setups, where I generate both corners and try to compare indexes, but if I understand, how the Index node functions, these setups run into the same problem as this one.
[image]

**Is there some way, how to modify my setup or some other setup of nodes, that would compute index of edge B_prev?**

Edit:

### Example

I am ading images of what I currently have and what I want.
Start with some mesh, e.g. cube.

[image: Cube]

After step 2, I have this result. (Image includes edges of the original cube)

[image]

In step 3, I want to set handles of splines, so the result looks like this - I have problem with computing that. (result was generated with this blender adon: https://github.com/BorisTheBrave/celtic-knot)

[image]

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) So you want to draw angles between edges?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I am not exactly sure, what do you mean by angles between edges. I added an example of what I am trying to achieve. I hope, I clarified the question.

Comment: It looks like you want to read the other face to access a corner there [geometry nodes - Get Faces of Edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291415/60486)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yes, reading other face and accessing a specific corner would solve my problem. I can see, how the solution you send can be used for comparing colors or other attributes of a face, but how can I use it for selecting the corner I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the solution is quite easy in Blender 4.0.0. I am sure, I tried this combination of nodes before, but probably did something else wrong, so I asumed, it was not working.

Solution:
[image: Solution]

You can see example of usage here:

[image] Blender 4.0.0 Alpha