# How to Select an Edge Created by a Boolean, in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, selection-tools

I have a basic geonode setup where one object punches a hole through another.  How would I select a specific edge created by the boole, so that I can then bevel it?

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j8yvkc5lpsnxitb57qib6/Select-Boole-Born-Edges.blend?rlkey=3iglvxzxewjtjzqhx2hop92oj&dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298669/

Comment: do you see the pink output of the `mesh boolean` node that says "intersecting edges". that is what it tells you.

Comment: @shmuel thanks, that makes sense. How would I use that output exactly? And how would I specify which intersecting edge I want to isolate for the bevel?

Comment: @GlenCandle you could use a `delete geometry` (set to `edge`) and a `boolean math` node (set to `not`) on the `intersecting edges` (to invert it) as the selection to output the edge.

Answer (score 2):

as @shmuel already said, you can use intersecting edges to get it. Just as an example, you how you could use extrude mesh to extend your geometry:

[image]

Comment: Very useful, thank you